# Calculate row wise percentage in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a data frame as shown below

```
id  val1  val2  val3
a   100   60    40
b   20    18    12
c   160   140   100
```

For each row I want to calculate the percentage.

The expected output as shown below

```
id  val1  val2  val3
a   50    30    20
b   40    36    24
c   40    35    25
```

I tried following code

```
df['sum'] = df['val1]+df['val2]+df['val3]
df['val1] = df['val1]/df['sum']
df['val2] = df['val2]/df['sum']
df['val3] = df['val3]/df['sum']
```

I would like to know is there any easy and alternate way than this in pandas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can do the following:

1. We slice the correct columns with `iloc`
2. Use `apply` with `axis=1` to apply each calculation row wise
3. We use `div`, `sum` and `mul` to divide each value to the rows sum and multiply it by 100 to get the percentages in whole numbers not decimals
4. We convert our `floats` back to `int` with `astype`

```
df.iloc[:, 1:] = df.iloc[:, 1:].apply(lambda x: x.div(x.sum()).mul(100), axis=1).astype(int)
```

**Output**

```
  id  val1  val2  val3
0  a    50    30    20
1  b    40    36    24
2  c    40    35    25
```

---

Or a vectorized solution, accessing the `numpy arrays` underneath our dataframe.

*note: this method should perform better in terms of speed*

```
df.iloc[:, 1:] = (df.iloc[:, 1:] / df.sum(axis=1)[:, None]).mul(100).astype(int)
```

---

Or similar but using the pandas `DataFrame.div` method:

*proposed by Jon Clements*

```
df.iloc[:, 1:] = df.iloc[:, 1:].div(df.iloc[:, 1:].sum(1), axis=0).mul(100)
```

Comment: Similar to the numpy approach, you can also use `DataFrame.div` and explicitly pass an axis eg: `df.iloc[:, 1:].div(df.iloc[:, 1:].sum(1), axis=0)` which some may find more readable...

Answer (score 0):

You may transpose your data frame and divide it by the sum of each row:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(1000, 1000)))
```

**much faster than the previous solution:**

```
%%timeit
(df.T/df.sum(axis=1)).T


5.04 ms ± 74.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```